# Непонятный WritePendingException

Tags: java, сокет, асинхронность, nio2

Есть сервер, на Java, работающий на асинхронных сокетах. Код сервера, примерно, такой

```
class ClientHandler implements CompletionHandler<Integer, ByteBuffer> {
  private final AsynchronousSocketChannel socket;
  private static final writer = new WriteHandler();

  public ClientHandler(AsynchronousSocketChannel socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
    doRead();
  }

  private void doRead() {
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(PACKET_SISE);
    socket.read(buf, buf, this);
  }

  private ByteBuffer process(ByteBuffer data) {
    .........
  }

  @Override
  public void completed(Integer result, ByteBuffer attachment) {
    if (attachment.hasRemaining()) {
      socket.close();
      return;
    }
    ByteBuffer buf = process(attachment);
    socket.write(buf, buf, writer);
    doRead();
  }

  @Override
  public void failed(Throwable exc, ByteBuffer attachment) {
    exc.printStackTrace();
  }
}

class WriteHandler implements CompletionHandler<Integer, ByteBuffer> {
  @Override
  public void completed(Integer result, ByteBuffer attachment) {
    if (attachment.hasRemaining())
      socket.close();
  }

  @Override
  public void failed(Throwable exc, ByteBuffer attachment) {
    exc.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Т.е. алгоритм простой - ждем пакета, определенной длины, обрабатываем его и отправляем результат.

И есть Win32 клиент, который работает на **блокирующем** сокете по такой схеме

```
while (data = getData()) {
  send(socket, &data, sizeof(data), 0);
  recv(socket, &data, sizeof(data), 0);
}
```

Сформировали новій пакет, отправили его, **дождались** результата, формируем новій пакет. Время формирования пакета очень мало.

Так, вот, уже на пятом-шестом пакете вызов на сервере `socket.write(buf, buf, writer);` приводит к исключению `WritePendingException`.

Я понимаю, что это за исключение и понимаю как с ним бороться. Я не понимаю как оно может возникнуть? Чтобы оно возникло, я должен записать в сокет данные до того, как отправились предыдущие. Но повторная запись возможна только при получении нового пакета, а это значит, что ответ по предыдущему пакету уже дошел до клиента и был обработан.

Такое ощущение, что в классе `AsynchronousSocketChannel` не синхронизирован метод `write()` в результате чего между отправкой данных и снятием флага `writePending` вклинивается обработка нового пакета

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот флаг сбрасывается перед вызовом коллбэка `completion`. Поэтому вариантов решения проблемы два

1. Инициировать ожидание следующего пакета в коллбэка `completion`
2. Реализовывать свою буферизацию